# How can use three different Gesture at the same time - TapGesture - LongPressGesture - DragGesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use these three gestures at the same time.

**TapGesture =** to able to scroll item

**LongPressGesture =** a menu pops up

**DragGesture =** to change view's offset

Here is my code; With this code, tapGesture and longPressGesture are working fine but some lags occurs on drag Gesture.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var viewOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("HEYOOOO")
             .padding()
        }
        .offset(viewOffset)
        .onTapGesture{}
        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
            //pops up a menu
            //xxx = true
        }
        
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.2)
                .onChanged{ gesture in
                    if gesture.translation.width > 0 {
                        viewOffset.width = gesture.translation.width
                    }
                }
                .onEnded{ _ in
                    viewOffset = .zero
                    
                })
    }
    
}
```

How can I prevent the lagging issue?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Your Example is not good example to try this gestures on it! why not making a right and clear example first, then asking!

Comment: @swiftPunk can you explain what is the true way to asking this question? What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Well your menu has no default code for some one that wants help you! Should this person code for menu as well? Or is it nice that you provide a working minimum example code. Or another issue where is your ScrollView? Should this person code for ScrollView as well? Also some other issues that I am not going name them all.

Comment: It is the base code. No one have to add somethings inside it to run it or see the gestures states. Secondly, you don't have to add menuView.  You can just put print("") code to see the longpressgesture work process if you want. The problem occurs or felt well on DragGesture as I mentioned. So there should not be an incomprehensible situation.